# Refresh controls when set value dynamically

Tags: sapui5

I have to set dynamically a text in the rich text editor to give the user the possibility to change it

```
      this.getView().byId("editedName").setValue(oModel.Names[index]);
```

the problem is  when i do

```
     this.getView().byId("editedName").getValue();
```

it returns correct value 
but the ritch text editor is empty and when i navigate back and forward it shows the value.

Comment: Could you share some more code and snapshots of the problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is solved by using the function rerender :
this.getView().byId("editedName").rerender();